# Получение исходного кода программы на C#

Tags: .net, c#

Есть программа, предположительно, на C#. Как посмотреть ее исходники?

Comment: Можно глянуть промежуточный код.(С условием чот он не был зашифрован).
Т.е. технология сама по себе какая: 1. Пишется код на c# 2. Конвертируется в помежуточный, который потом, в свою очередь, уже переходит в 10001001001110010 и т.д. ))) ПОсмотреть промежуточный код без шифрования вполне реально:) Но подсказывать как это сделать не буду. Сам просто попалился давно на этой хрени. Мне как азработчику было крайне неприятно....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Дизассемблер .NET сборок: [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

Answer (score 5):

- Reflector
- dotPeek
- Dis#
- Salamander
     .NET Decompiler

Answer (score 1):

Спустя много времени, но вдруг кому то ещё пригодится:

- [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)
- [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

Обе бесплатные, open-source.